# html is showing SVG tag as plain text not as image

Tags: android, html, node.js, svg

Iam sending svg from **android** to **node js** then i put the svg in my html then convert it into PDF,my pdf shows the SVG code as plain text not as an image, **the same code is working in any HTML and shows the image**

HTML :

```
<p>Signature :{{intervention.client_signature}}</p>
```

The svg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n' +
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" height="600" width="990" viewBox="0 0 990 600"><g stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" stroke="black"><path stroke-width="18" d="M727,407c0,0 0,0 0,0 "/><path stroke-width="21" d="M727,407c0,0 0,0 0,0 "/><path stroke-width="15" d="M727,407c-13,-11 -12,-12 -26,-22 "/><path stroke-width="9" d="M701,385c-47,-32 -46,-35 -96,-62 -55,-30 -56,-30 -114,-51 -51,-19 -52,-16 -105,-28 -41,-10 -42,-10 -83,-15 -40,-5 -40,-7 -79,-7 -28,0 -29,-1 -55,7 -16,5 -18,6 -29,19 -8,9 -12,13 -8,23 8,23 10,29 32,43 40,27 44,23 91,39 49,16 50,15 100,26 62,14 62,15 125,26 52,8 52,7 105,11 37,3 37,3 74,2 32,-1 34,2 65,-6 30,-8 32,-8 57,-27 28,-20 31,-21 48,-50 20,-33 18,-36 27,-75 8,-39 10,-41 7,-81 -3,-43 -2,-45 -18,-84 -18,-42 -20,-44 -52,-77 -28,-31 -31,-30 -68,-51 -30,-18 -32,-15 -65,-26 -27,-9 -27,-11 -54,-15 -22,-3 -23,-4 -44,1 -21,6 -23,7 -40,21 -16,12 -19,13 -28,31 -15,31 -15,33 -21,67 -7,39 -3,40 -4,80 -1,42 0,42 1,84 0,33 2,34 1,67 -1,30 -1,31 -5,61 -4,25 -4,25 -11,49 -5,14 -5,14 -12,27 -6,12 -5,13 -14,23 -9,10 -10,10 -22,17 -14,8 -14,8 -30,14 -18,6 -18,7 -37,10 -22,3 -22,2 -45,2 -24,-1 -24,0 -47,-4 -27,-5 -27,-6 -52,-14 -24,-8 -25,-7 -46,-20 -17,-11 -16,-13 -31,-28 -13,-13 -14,-13 -25,-29 -5,-8 -6,-8 -7,-17 "/><path stroke-width="10" d="M87,368c-1,-9 -3,-14 4,-18 29,-15 33,-17 68,-20 "/><path stroke-width="9" d="M159,330c61,-6 62,-2 124,2 63,4 63,8 126,13 48,3 48,3 97,3 40,0 40,2 80,-2 31,-3 32,-5 62,-13 24,-7 25,-7 48,-17 14,-6 14,-7 26,-15 16,-11 20,-8 29,-23 23,-42 18,-49 35,-92 "/></g></svg>
```

Comment: can you share an example of SVG?

Comment: Done @SergeyRudenko

Comment: this is what my pdf looks like https://ibb.co/qgR3ZxG